# Using generating functions in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I know these questions get asked a lot but I cannot figure it out. It requires the use of generating functions to find the number of solutions (coefficient) to the equation:

$u_i+u_2+u_3+u_4 = 20$, where $1 \leq u_i \leq 5, i = 1,...,4$

How do I solve this question step-by-step?

Thanks.

Comment: There is only one solution, right? (Or am I missing something?) Why would you use generating functions?

Comment: It's more of an exercise in generating functions. I'll be applying the technique to other questions... once I understand it properly.

Comment: This can also be done more easily by principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: Let $v_i = 5-u_i$. Then $v_i \geq 0$ and we need $v_1+v_2+v_3+v_4 = 20 - (u_1+u_2+u_4) = 0$ and hence the only solution is $v_i = 0$ for all $i$. Thus there is only one solution.

Answer (score 3):

I will take the case of equation $u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4+u_5=20$ because it provides a more interesting challenge.

The main idea is to transfer this issue into an issue about exponents, namely:

$$\tag{1}\underbrace{(x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) \times (x^1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) \times 
 \cdots }_{5 \ \text{factors}}=$$

$$\tag{2}(x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)^5$$

It suffices now to expand (2) (using a CAS = Computer Algebra System)

$$\tag{3}x^5+5x^6+15x^7+\cdots+121x^{20}+\cdots+15x^{23}+5x^{24}+x^{25}.$$

and collect the coefficient of $x^{20}$...

Why that ? Because the number of times one obtains $x^{20}$ is the number of times, by picking, in relationship (1), a certain $x^{u_1}$ inside the first parenthesis, a certain $x^{u_2}$ in the second parenthesis, etc. In this way, one gets a $x^{u_1+u_2+...}$ and we are interested in those that sum up to $20$...

Remark: In each factor of (1), the range of exponents, i.e., $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ corresponds to the domain constraints: $ \ 1 \leq u_i \leq 5$.

Comment: This finds all the solutions for 0<=u(i)<=5 and not 1<=u(i)<=5.

Comment: You are right. I am going to rectify it.

Answer (score 3):

> The constraint $1\leq u_i \leq 5$ can be encoded using the *[finite geometric series formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* as
>   \begin{align*}
> z^1+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5=\frac{z\left(1-z^5\right)}{1-z}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since (1) holds for each $u_i, 1\leq i\leq 4$ all possible configurations can be encoded as
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(\frac{z\left(1-z^5\right)}{1-z}\right)^4\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We want to find the number of non-negative integer solutions of
\begin{align*}
u_1+u_2+u_3+u_4=20
\end{align*}
with the constraints given above.

> In the following we denote with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$. According to (2) we are looking for 
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^{20}]&z^4\frac{\left(1-z^5\right)^4}{(1-z)^4}\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^{16}]\frac{\left(1-z^5\right)^4}{(1-z)^4}\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^{16}]\left(1-4z^5+6z^{10}-4z^{15}\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-4}{k}(-z)^k\tag{5}\\
> &=\left([z^{16}]-4[z^{11}]+6[z^{6}]-4[z]\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+3}{3}z^k\tag{6}\\
> &=\binom{19}{3}-4\binom{14}{3}+6\binom{9}{3}-4\binom{4}{3}\tag{7}\\
> &=969-4\cdot364+6\cdot84-4\cdot 4\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance with the obvious single solution $u_1=u_2=u_3=u_4=5$.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we select the coefficient of $[z^{20}]$ of the product of the generating function (2) which correspond to the valid ranges specified for $u_i$ with   $1\leq i \leq 4$.
- In (4) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we multiply out the numerator and skip terms with powers greater than $16$ since they do not contribute to $[z^{16}]$. We also apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (6) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, apply the same rule as in (4) four times and use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (7) we select the coefficients accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3} + u_{4} = 20\quad\mbox{where}\quad
> 1 \leq u_{i} \leq 5\,,\ i = 1,\ldots,4}$.
>   
>   How do I solve this question $\ds{\underline{\texttt{step-by-step}}}$ ?.

The "$\ds{\underline{\texttt{step-by-step}}}$" answer is given by
\begin{align}
\sum_{u_{1} = 1}^{5}\sum_{u_{2} = 1}^{5}\sum_{u_{3} = 1}^{5}
\sum_{u_{4} = 1}^{5}
\overbrace{\qquad\qquad\bracks{z^{20}}z^{u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3} + u_{4}}\qquad\qquad}
^{\ds{\substack{%
\ds{= 1}\,\,\, \mbox{if}\,\,\, u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3} + u_{4} = 20
\\[2mm]
\ds{\ds{= 0}\,\,\, \mbox{otherwise}}}}}
\end{align}
The multiple sum adds $\ds{1}$ each time it encounters the case $\ds{u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3} + u_{4} = 20}$. Otherwise, it adds 'nothing' which means it adds $\ds{0}$. That makes the whole job. Then,
\begin{align}
&\sum_{u_{1} = 1}^{5}\sum_{u_{2} = 1}^{5}\sum_{u_{3} = 1}^{5}
\sum_{u_{4} = 1}^{5}\bracks{z^{20}}z^{u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3} + u_{4}} =
\bracks{z^{20}}\sum_{u_{1} = 1}^{5}z^{u_{1}}
\sum_{u_{2} = 1}^{5}z^{u_{2}}\sum_{u_{3} = 1}^{5}z^{u_{3}}
\sum_{u_{4} = 1}^{5}z^{u_{4}} =
\bracks{z^{20}}\pars{\sum_{u = 1}^{5}z^{u}}^{4}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{20}}\pars{z\,{z^{5} - 1 \over z - 1}}^{4} =
\bracks{z^{20}}z^{\color{red}{\large 4}}\,{\pars{1 - z^{5}}^{4} \over
\pars{1 - z}^{4}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{20 - \color{#f00}{\large 4}}}\pars{1 - 4z^{\color{#f00}{5}} +
6z^{\color{#f00}{10}} - 4z^{\color{#f00}{15}} + z^{\color{#f00}{20}}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{z^{16}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} -
4\bracks{z^{16 - \color{#f00}{5}}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} +
6\bracks{z^{16 - \color{#f00}{10}}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4}
\\[2mm] - &\
4\bracks{z^{16 - \color{#f00}{15}}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} +
\bracks{z^{16 - \color{#f00}{20}}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4}
\\[4mm] = &\
{-4 \choose 16}\pars{-1}^{16} - 4{-4 \choose 11}\pars{-1}^{11} +
6{-4 \choose 6}\pars{-1}^{6} - 4{-4 \choose 1}\pars{-1}^{1} +
{-4 \choose -4}\pars{-1}^{-4}
\\[5mm] = &
{19 \choose 3} - 4{14 \choose 11} + 6{9 \choose 6} -4{4 \choose 1} +
{1 \choose -4}
\\[5mm] = &\
969 - 4 \times 364 + 6 \times 84 - 4 \times 4 + 0 = \bbx{1}
\end{align}