# Balls in urns with different max capacity for each urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, problem-solving, balls-in-bins

I'm looking to figure out the formula for putting K balls in N urns, where each of the N urns has a specific max capacity. For example,

- Urn A has capacity for at most 5 balls
- Urn B has capacity for at most 2 balls
- Urn C has capacity for at most 1 ball
- Urn D has capacity for at most 2 balls

How many ways are there to put 5 indistinguishable balls in urns A, B, C and D?

With brute-force code, I know that this example has these 18 solutions:

(0, 2, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 1, 2)
(1, 2, 0, 2)
(1, 2, 1, 1)
(2, 0, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 0, 2)
(2, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 2, 0, 1)
(2, 2, 1, 0)
(3, 0, 0, 2)
(3, 0, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 0, 1)
(3, 1, 1, 0)
(3, 2, 0, 0)
(4, 0, 0, 1)
(4, 0, 1, 0)
(4, 1, 0, 0)
(5, 0, 0, 0)

But I'm having trouble coming up with a general formula, which I need for my application, where the numbers get too large to brute-force like this. Does anyone know how to compute the number of combinations for putting indistinguishable balls in urns, only with max capacity for each urn?

Comment: You can use generating function or stars and bars along with principle of inclusion exclusion. But for bigger numbers, generating function would scale better (I am assuming you are writing a program)

Comment: @MathLover I have the code to create a generating function, but I really just need the number of combinations, not each combination; that's what I'm looking for here. I'm aiming to avoid iterating through all the many combinations.

What do you mean by stars and bars with the principle of inclusion exclusion?

Comment: For generating function, if an urn can have max of $1$ ball, write it as $(x^0+x^1)$ or $(1+x)$, if it can have at most $2$ balls write it as $(1+x+x^2)$ and so on... So it comes down to finding coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x) (1+x+x^2)^2 (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)$

Comment: @MathLover Oh, interesting! I was thinking of a generator, I'd forgotten about this usage of generating function. Would the same function work for different sets of maxima? I have many thousands of maxima

Comment: Wild guess: $\frac{m!}{n_1!n_2!...n_N!}$ where $n_k\le N_k$, and $n_k $ is no. balls with $N_k$ is capacity of urn $k$ among $N$  and $\sum n_k=m$ is number of balls.

Comment: @herbsteinberg That looks like what I'm looking for! But I'm not sure I follow the exact formula — can you walk through how you would use it on the example & recover the value 18?

Comment: As stated it is incorrect.  It needs a summation over combinations of  $n_k$.    It may turn out no better than brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching, and in particular looking at the answers to this post [Number of ways to distribute indistinguishable balls into distinguishable boxes of given size](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707996/number-of-ways-to-distribute-indistinguishable-balls-into-distinguishable-boxes?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this post [Using generating functions in combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269523/using-generating-functions-in-combinatorics), I realize that @MathLover's comment above is right — thank you! Quoted here:

> For generating function, if an urn can have max of 1 ball, write it as $(_0+_1)$ or $(1+)$, if it can have at most 2 balls write it as $(1++_2)$ and so on... So it comes down to finding coefficient of $_5$ in $(1+)(1++_2)^2(1++_2+_3+_4+_5)$

For those less interested in the pure formula than in the implementation, as I am, here's the code I'm now using:

```
import numpy as np

def comb_r_under_max(r,max_by_urn):
  mul = np.poly1d(np.ones(max_by_urn[0]+1)) # initializing polynomial
  for deg in max_by_urn[1:]:
    mul = np.polymul(np.poly1d(np.ones(deg+1)), mul) # multiplying
  return int(mul[r])

  
# test on our example
max_by_urn = [5,2,1,2]
r = 5

print(comb_r_under_max(r,max_by_urn)) # prints 18
```

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to solve this kind of problems with recusion and lru_cache, from ground up, code can be simplified but I am sure you can work it out

```
@lru_cache
def get_combs(no_balls: int, urns: tuple) -> int:
    if no_balls == 0:
        return 1
    if no_balls > sum(urns):
        return 0
    if len(urns) ==  1:
        if urns[0]>=no_balls:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    res = 0
    for i in range(min(urns[0], no_balls)+1):
        res += get_combs(no_balls-i, urns[1:])
    return res
```